Interrump a while function with a press button
There's a function that control a dispersing liquid with a while condition when the weight goal is attempt.
I am triying to introduce a pause/resume inside to the while but it didn't work. I already set the same press button inside other function when the liquid is empty and when I press the button resume the task
The code is writed in spanish and english:

void Mezclas::echarLiquido(int16_t pesoPorechar)
{
  // Encender la bomba correspondiente
  encenderBombaCorrespondiente();

  unsigned long tiempoInicioMezcla = millis(); 
  unsigned long tiempoUltimaVariacion = millis();
  pesoLiquido = PesoActual();
  pesoRelative = 0;
  EEPROM.get(PESO_RELATIVO_ADDRESS, pesoRelative);
  // Mostrar el mensaje adecuado en el LCD
  mostrarLiquido();
  delay(50);

  // Condition to attempt the weight goal
  while (pesoRelative < pesoPorechar)
  {
    // Pause button is pressed
    if(botonPausa.pulsado())
    {
      delay(20);
      pausarReanudarMezcla();
    }

    // Resuming the function
    if (enPausa)
    {
      esperarParaReanudar();
    }

    // Condition of the time error pomp 
    if (millis() - tiempoInicioMezcla > tiempoErrorBomba)
    {
      lcd.clear();
      delay(20);
      lcd.setCursor(1,0);
      lcd.print("ERROR BOMBA");
      delay(8000);
      apagarBombas();
      return;
    }
    
    mostrarLiquido();
    
    int16_t nuevoPesoActual = PesoActual();
   
    
    if (nuevoPesoActual != pesoLiquido)
    {
      tiempoUltimaVariacion = millis(); // Reiniciar el temporizador si hay cambio en el peso
    }
    
    // if the weight don't increase it mean's the liquid is exhausted
    if (millis() - tiempoUltimaVariacion > 15000) // Si no hay cambio en el peso por 5 segundos
    {
      mostrarAgotado();
      apagarBombas();

      // wait until the pause button is pressed to continue and resuming 
      while (!botonAgotado.pulsado())
      {
        delay(300);
      }

      // Reiniciar la bomba correspondiente
      encenderBombaCorrespondiente();

      // Reiniciar el tiempo de última variación
      tiempoUltimaVariacion = millis();
    }
     // resuming the section of the liauid measurement
    nuevoPesoActual = PesoActual();
    pesoRelative += nuevoPesoActual - pesoLiquido;
    pesoLiquido = nuevoPesoActual;
    EEPROM.put(PESO_RELATIVO_ADDRESS, pesoRelative);
    updateProgressBar(pesoRelative, pesoPorechar, 1); 
    delay(500);
 }

  // The end of the function 
  pesoLiquido = PesoActual();
  EEPROM.put(PESO_ACEITE_ACTUAL_ADRESS, pesoLiquido);
  EEPROM.put(PESO_RELATIVO_ADDRESS, 0);
  
  // Apagar la bomba correspondiente
  apagarBombas();

  delay(1000);

void Mezclas::pausarReanudarMezcla()
{
  enPausa = !enPausa;
  if (enPausa)
  {
    Pantallamezcla(8);
  }
  else
  {
    Pantallamezcla(9);
    delay(3000);
  }
}

void Mezclas::esperarParaReanudar()
{
  while (enPausa)
  {
    // Esperar hasta que se reanude la mezcla
    if (botonPausa.pulsado())
    {
      pausarReanudarMezcla();
    }
  }
}

}


I tried to manage the pause button but it didn't work

What is your target platform?  Interrupts are handled differently on Windows and Linux.  For embedded systems, depends on how the button is wired up and the processor (System On A Chip).

People will be able to help better if you can provide the code in English. For more information see https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions.

The code looks like for Arduino but it is incomplete and non-compilable. We don't know how button reading is implemented. Since there are busy-loop delays, probably you can't just add a condition for button pressed/released. You should re-view your finite state machine design.

I am programming an Atmega1284P in an Arduino platform via platform.io. In this case i already have a button library to manage the pressing buttons detection and it works perfectly in other functions like in the menus management that I programmed.
The problem is when the while condition is keeping true, the pressed button can't response.
